# How to pull out all characters from a to b in a string using regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex, mediawiki

So I have a sections of text that is part of a larger body. I am trying to pull out one specific section... (The text is MediaWiki code by the way). Basically what I am trying to do is replace everything starting from `{{` and ending at `}}` INCLUSIVE (brackets should be grabbed also).

```
| locator map      = {{Location map|island of Ireland|relief=yes|caption=|float=center|marksize=5|lat= 53.50073|long=-10.14984}}
```

Now the current ruby REGEX I have is shown below and this works great if all the parameters are on one line as in the example above.

```
\|\s*locator\smap\s*=\s*\{\{[Ll]ocation map\s*\|(?<map>[A-Za-z0-9\s]*).*caption\s*=\s*(?<caption>[^\|]*).*\}\}
```

However, if the parameters are on multiple lines such as below, then the regular expression breaks.

```
| locator map      = {{Location map
  |Island of Ireland
  |relief=yes|caption=|float=center
  |marksize=5|lat= 53.50073|long=-10.14984
}}
| coords = {{coord|12|12|}}
```

Note tht the last line should NOT be selected by the REGEX. I do not have my heart set on using regular expressions... If there is an easier way to get what I need, perhaps using Ruby's String class, that would be fine by me!

Comment: Please show what you want the return values to be, especially in the second example.

Comment: MediaWiki syntax allows nested template calls, e.g. `{{foo|{{bar}}}}`. Do you need to support those?

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple:

```
\|\s*locator\smap[\s\S]+\}\}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/BEUGNn/1

The code above gets you the same results that your code does. However, if you want to match only what is between the curly brackets `{ }` as indicated in your question, You can try the Regex LookAround function which is allowed in Rupy. Try this code:

```
(?<=\|\slocator\smap\s{6}\=\s\{\{)[\s\S]+\d+(?=\}\})
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/2JfrJU/1

Comment: This doesn't work as it grabs the last `}}` on the page. Not the first one. See the updated example.

Comment: you seem to have misunderstood... The brackets should be grabbed also.

Comment: @Zack I updated my second code, check it out, and check also the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
R = /
    (?<={{) # match two left brackets in a positive lookbehind
    .*      # match any number of any character, greedily
    (?=}})  # match two right brackets in a positive lookahead
    /xm  # free-spacing regex definition and multi-line modes

def replace_it(str, replacement)
  str.sub(R, replacement)
end
```

**Examples**

```
str =<<-END
| locator map      = {{Location map
  |Island of Ireland
  |relief=yes|caption=|float=center
  |marksize=5|lat= 53.50073|long=-10.14984
}}
END

str[R]
  #=> "Location map\n      |Island...|long=-10.14984\n    "

replace_it(str, "How now, brown cow?")
  #=> "    | locator map      = {{How now, brown cow?}}\n"
```

Another example:

```
str = "| locator map = {{pig{{dog}}cat}}"

str[R]
  #=> "pig{{dog}}cat"
replace_it(str, "How now, brown cow?")
  #=> "| locator map = {{How now, brown cow?}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oniguruma's subroutines to make it work even when you have nested curlies:

```
text = <<TEXT
| locator map      = {{Location map
  |Island of {{country}}                 <-- NESTED CURLY HERE
  |relief=yes|caption=|float=center
  |marksize=5|lat= 53.50073|long=-10.14984
}}
| coords = {{coord|12|12|}}
TEXT


field_name = "locator map"

re = %r[
  #{Regexp.escape(field_name)}   # find the key we want
  \s* = \s*                      # then the equals sign
  (?<curlies>                    # start subroutine (also the final capture region)
   {{                            # opening curlies, then
    (?:                          # any number of
      \g<curlies>                # full curly tag
      |                          # or
      (?!{{).                    # any character that would not start a curly tag
    )*
   }}                            # then closing curlies
  )
]xm                              # extended syntax, multiline matching

puts text[re, :curlies]          # extract the curlies region
# => {{Location map
       |Island of {{country}}                 <-- NESTED CURLY HERE
       |relief=yes|caption=|float=center
       |marksize=5|lat= 53.50073|long=-10.14984
     }}

text[re, :curlies] = "SOMETHING" # replace it with something
puts text
# => | locator map      = SOMETHING
     | coords = {{coord|12|12|}}
```

Of course you can also use the other Regexp methods like `gsub`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion REGEX is easier way to solve your task. It's shortest way. If you want to work with parameters on multiple lines, you should use "m" modifier. It will looks like this: `/your REGEX here/m`. If your REGEX select too long string, it means you use greedy version of quantifiers. Greedy quantifiers looking for longest substrings that match the pattern. Not greedy quantifiers looking for shortest matches. For using not greedy version put "?" after quantifier. For your example

```
| locator map      = {{Location map
  |Island of Ireland
  |relief=yes|caption=|float=center
  |marksize=5|lat= 53.50073|long=-10.14984
}}
| coords = {{coord|12|12|}}
```

right REGEX will be:

```
/\|\s*locator\smap\s*=\s*\{\{[Ll]ocation map\s*\|(?<map>[A-Za-z0-9\s]*).*caption\s*=\s*(?<caption>[^\|]*).*?\}\}/m
```

There is great project [rubular.com](http://rubular.com) in Internet. You can check your regular expressions here. It shows result immediately without any code writing. It can make your work with regular expressions faster even if you don't love them.